# Maya API add/remove vertices/edges from existing mesh

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

Is there a way to add/remove vertices, edges and faces from existing meshes with Python API? I found a few question around the web about this, but all without answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [OpenMaya.MFnMesh](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_1_1_m_fn_mesh_html) there are some methods for this:

- To delete:

  - deleteEdge(edgeId, modifier=None) -> self
  - deleteFace(faceId, modifier=None) -> self
  - deleteVertex(vertexId, modifier=None) -> self
- To add:

  - addPolygon(vertices, mergeVertices=True, pointTolerance=kPointTolerance, loopCounts=None) -> faceId; Which merges vertices within a certain range (pointTolerance).

So it seems like you cannot just create single vertices and then properly connect them with edges and faces, but you have to define a complete polygon.

If there are other solutions I would be happy to know!